# angular standalone component not woking in child or shared componnent

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular application with core, shared and feature modules. I have the opportunity to update bit by bit the application with new standalone components. But it does not work everywhere.

Here is an stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2repu6?file=src%2Fmain.ts
(sorry but I do not know how to boostrap it on stackblitz)

I succeeded to make work standalone component in some cases except in a shared component or in a child component of a feature module.
The error I get is : [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-standalone' is not a known element

I do not understand what is wrong. Even after reading about standalone components. Maybe it is simple. But I have not understood what I missed.

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Standalone component : works

No problem, because you are lazy loading `StandaloneComponent (standalone: true)` and since it has `StandaloneChildComponent (standalone: true)` in its imports, its loading without any issues!

---

#### 2. Feature component : works

No problem, you are having `StandaloneComponent (standalone: true)` in the imports array of `FeatureModule`, which means, we can use it in the html of featureComponent as `<app-standalone />`

---

#### 3. Feature child component : does not work!

Problem, because `FeatureChildComponent (standalone: false)` has not been added to the declarations array of `FeatureModule`, that is why you are getting the error for `'app-standalone' is not a known element`.Since the `StandaloneComponent` lies in the imports of `FeatureModule`, we need to have `FeatureChildComponent` declaration in the `FeatureModule` for `app-standalone` to be usable!

---

#### 4. Shared component in Feature : does not work !

Problem, because `SharedComponent (standalone: false)` has not been added to the declarations array of `SharedModule`, that is why you are getting the error for `'app-standalone' is not a known element`. Since the `StandaloneComponent` lies in the imports of `SharedModule`, we need to have the `SharedComponent` declaration in the `SharedModule` for `app-standalone` to be usable!

---

#### Note: When you have a standalone component, that needs to be used in scenarios other than routing, add it to the imports array of a `module/standalone component`!

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mhl2gu?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-rounting.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-child%2Ffeature-child.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature.module.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared%2Fshared.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-child%2Ffeature-child.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared%2Fshared.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

In `feature.module.ts` you need to add `FeatureChildComponent` to `declarations`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { FeatureRoutingModule } from './feature-rounting.module';
import { FeatureComponent } from './feature/feature.component';
import { StandaloneComponent } from '../standalone/standalone.component';
import { FeatureChildComponent } from './feature-child/feature-child.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [FeatureComponent, FeatureChildComponent],
  imports: [SharedModule, FeatureRoutingModule, StandaloneComponent],
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

In `shared.component.html` remove `imports` does not work because no standalone component.

In `shared.module.ts` you need to add `SharedComponent` to `declarations`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StandaloneComponent } from '../standalone/standalone.component';
import { SharedComponent } from './shared/shared.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SharedComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, StandaloneComponent],
  exports: [CommonModule],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

For a detailed explanation look @Naren Murali answer