# Angular v17 CLI Default to Standalone: Does Lazy Loading Still Require @NgModule for Routing?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, lazy-loading, angular17

Angular v17 onwards defaults to the Standalone approach in the CLI, and there's no more explicit use of @NgModule for application organization. My question is regarding lazy loading with the new default configuration.

Suppose I define my routes in the following way (as im using standalone components):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {'path' : '', component: DashboardComponent},
    {'path' : 'users', component: UsersComponent},
    {'path' : '**', component: DashboardComponent},
];
```

Will lazy loading still work with this new standalone-oriented approach, or is it necessary to adhere to the traditional @NgModule and feature module way to apply the lazy loading concept in Angular v17? I'd appreciate any insights, experiences, or documentation references related to this potential change in behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use lazy loading for a standalone component, you can use [`loadComponent`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#properties) instead of `component`!

[Lazy loading a standalone component - Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#lazy-loading-a-standalone-component)

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {'path': '', component: DashboardComponent},
    {
      // here users route component will get lazy loaded, by using a callback with import statement!
      'path': 'users', 
      loadComponent: () =>
      import('./app/users/users.component').then(
        (mod) => mod.UsersComponent
      ),
    },
    {'path': '**', component: DashboardComponent},
];
```

You can still use `ngModules` its acceptable, its just that standalone is the new mainstream way to do it.

Here is a stackblitz where both are implemented, from another SO question

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852468/angular-standalone-component-not-woking-in-child-or-shared-componnent)

[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mhl2gu?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-rounting.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-child%2Ffeature-child.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature.module.ts,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared%2Fshared.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Ffeature%2Ffeature-child%2Ffeature-child.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fshared%2Fshared.component.ts)